# How to calculate congruence modulo using Euclid's algorithm?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences

How to find all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ that satisfy this congruence modulo:

$15x\equiv 5 \mod25$.

So, I know that first thing I need to check is if $\gcd(a,m)$ is dividing $b$. In our case $a$ is $15$, $b$ is $5$ and $m$ is $25$, therefore $\gcd(15,25) = 5$. We see that our $b$ can be divided by $\gcd$, so we can divide whole congruence modulo with 5, and we get this:

$3x\equiv 1 \mod5$.

We can also write this as $3x + 5k = 1$.

After Euclid's algorithm and making the table, I get this.

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
a_i&1& 0& 1& -1 \\ \hline
 b_i&0& 1& -1& 2\\ \hline
 q_i&&  & 1& 1& 2\\ \hline
 &5& 3& 2& 1& 0\\ \hline
\end{array}$

From this I am not sure how should I precede. I can confirm $3x + 5k = 1$ by putting last $a$ and $b$ instead of $k$ and $x$, but I really don't have idea what should I do next.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: What are $a_i$, $b_i$, $q_i$ in the table?

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple: $3$ is a unit mod. $5$ and its inverse is $2$, so
$$3x\equiv 1\mod 5\iff2(3x)=(2\cdot 3)x\equiv x\equiv 2\mod 5.$$

Comment: Could you explain this a little bit more?

Comment: Well, I use the usual rules for congruences: I multiplied both sides by $2$, (the inverse of $3$, so as to obtain $x\equiv$ on the l.h.s., and the congruence equation becomes $x\equiv 2\mod 5$. What's not clear in this procedure?